# Exception thrown and not caught at require-object-coercible in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, babeljs, core-js

I'm using Babel to transpile my ES7 code. My setup is a bit strange because I need to transpile some *node_modules*. I keep getting this error:

> SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
>   require-object-coercible.js (4,24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought my config was wrong and I was transpiling incorrect modules (since you shouldn't transpile [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)) but after some digging around, I found out that the problem was in my code.

I was calling [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children). `from()` should be called on an iterable input and in Chrome, the `children` property always returns an HTMLCollection, which is iterable. In IE, however, `children` of an SVG element is `undefined`, which raises the error in `require-object-coercible`. This makes my code work fine on Chrome, but not in IE11, even after correct polyfills.

The solution was to simply perform a check on `children` before calling `from()`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I had the same issue. It was only after debugging the call stack that I could find the origin of it. For those who face the same problem, go to IE11 debugger, change the exception behavior to "break on unhandled exceptions", and look at the call stack, it will help you find the origin.

For me it was a call to `Object.keys(window.XXX)` where window.XXX was undefined.